# how do i style some part of the shape in hover?

Tags: javascript, mousehover

the bigger circle is the mouse cursor and the small one is a fixed circle in the center of the page,
how can style this circle like the image when the cursor touches some area of the center circle?
[image]

Comment: Please show the code you are using to create the cursor, preferably in a runnable snippet as that makes it much easier for us to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a large circle being used like the cursor and using mix-blend-mode difference.

The background of the container is blue (#0000ff) and the circles are yellow (#ffff00) so that the difference is white (#ffffff).

When the circles overlap the difference is #000000 and that differenced with blue is blue.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Circles</title>
  <style>
    .bg {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background: blue;
      mix-blend-mode: difference;
      cursor: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .fixedcircle {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: yellow;
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: calc(50% - 50px);
      left: calc(50% - 50px);
      position: relative;
      position: fixed;
      mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }
    
    .cursor {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: yellow;
      position: absolute;
      mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="fixedcircle"></div>
  <script>
    const cursor = document.createElement('div');
    cursor.classList.add('cursor');
    document.body.append(cursor);
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
      cursor.style.top = (event.clientY - 100) + 'px';
      cursor.style.left = (event.clientX - 100) + 'px';
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks but want the big circle to be mouse cursor

Comment: So is your problem that  you don't know how to create the mouse cursor circle? Please show us the code you have so far in your question. As your question is currently phrased I thought the problem was to find out how to get the overlap effect.

Comment: I've changed the answer so that the big circle acts like the cursor.. Note, if you run the code outside the SO snippet system then the actual cursor is not seen so the circle does take on the role of cursor as far as the user is concerned. You also don't need the intermediate bg div, the blue could be on the body.

Comment: thanks, now i just need to change it for react